# How can I make a js function recognize a clicked or empty checkbox?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onclick

I'm modifiying an existing form.

You can launch a task block with several fields, and if these are all empty, you can remove the block again. Most of them are required, to submit as data complete. If not complete, you can save Work in Process (sic! I'd have preferred Work in Progress...)

For the code to recognize empty fields, it seems that most of them have `value=""`. When completed, the system seems to to recognize that they are not empty.

But the Checkbox I want to use causes problems.

If I don't set `value=""`, it's not recognized as empty, and I can't remove the block.

If I set `value=""` , it's not recognizing an entered checkmark, and I can't submit for Data Complete.

I thought that `onClick="...."` and defining a way to set `value="true"` would be a way forward, but haven't found any example while searching, and being quite the beginner, I haven't learned it all yet.

the checkbox (to be renumbered up to id 050):

```
<label for="completed_001">Task Completed<em class="labelrequired">*</em></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="completed_001" name="completed_001" alt="Task Completed 001" title="Task Completed 001" value="" class="validate['required']">
```

the function: (where the last row concerns the checkbox)

```
function isEmptyAction(nr) {

    var pad = "000";
    var nr = (pad+nr).slice(-pad.length);

    return  document.getElementById('taskdescription' + nr).value == '' &&
            document.getElementById('TaskOwner' + nr).value == '' &&
            document.getElementById('taskduedate' + nr + '_date').value == '' &&
            document.getElementById('documentid' + nr).value == '' &&
            document.getElementById('resultsandcomments' + nr).value == '' &&
            document.getElementById('completed_' + nr).value == '';  
}
```

= = = = = UPDATE = = = =

1) thanks for the edit improvement, fellow user dmorrow!

2) Thanks for the tips and suggestions, I got it to work eventually!

I removed the `value=""` from the checkbox code in the html. 
This allows the entered checkmark to be recognized, when required for sumbmitting Data Complete.

I used  `document.getElementById('completed_' + nr).checked == false;`  in the function for checking that all fields are empty. 
This allows removing the task block when empty.

Thanks again! You made me a happy beginner!

Comment: I think you want `checked==true`

Comment: it needs to be empty to be able to remove a block that was launched but not used.

Comment: can you update the code with a working snippet? using the `<>` icon in the editor

Comment: Not sure how to do that yet, just joined the forum...
I barely managed to get the checkbox code snippet in.

there are several functions about these blocks, initActions(), addAction(), removeAction() and isEmptyAction(nr). removeAction calls isEmptyAction to make sure removing the Action (task block) is legal.

Comment: I've only changed the isEmptyAction, to check for the right property.
In the task blocks, I changed the complete check from a Date Completed to just a checkbox. 
Perhaps I have to leave it as a date, if the checkbox value can't be recognised from "" to "true".

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
 document.getElementById('completed_' + nr).value == '';
```

if you don't have a value or an empty value, it will always return true. Because instead of checked status, you are only checking it's value attribute. Instead you need to use

```
  document.getElementById('completed_' + nr).checked;
```

Then it will return true/false depending on status of checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to make sense to me! 
So, will this work, to make sure that the function "passes" when the checkbox is empty? Or does the function have to say something else to ensure this? 
Do I still need to use the value="" for the checkbox in the html section?

Comment: No if you only need to checked state of the checkbox, that's how it is. but if you are updating the checkbox somewhere else and need to check if it has a value, and checked then you may use it like `(document.getElementById('completed_' + nr).checked && document.getElementById('completed_' + nr).value !== '')`

Comment: from the checkbox code, I removed the value=""

In the function, i changed from .value == ""; to .checked;

Unfortunately, the code no longer allows removing an empty block of task actions. 

is it possible to define .checked == false ?

Comment: Then you will be only checking existence of the element, rather than checked status or value.

Comment: You are very patient!

so, .checked == false will only verify that there is a checkbox?

In the function I need to know that there is a checkbox and that it is empty...

Comment: No problem at all. I will add as an answer below. It will give longer comment area.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you would like to check `existence` of checkbox field then you need

```
  document.getElementById('completed_' + nr)
```

if you need the value of the checkbox either `checked` or `not checked`

```
  document.getElementById('completed_' + nr).value
```

if you need the value if checkbox is `checked`

```
  ( document.getElementById('completed_' + nr).checked && document.getElementById('completed_' + nr).value!=='' )
```

Be aware of the parentheses. This will return only true if `both` cases are true.